# Binding observable collection to listview doesn't pass items in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a problem with binding observable collection to listview in Xamarin.iOS. My code works in Android and UWP project, but not in the iOS (in simulator).

I have a datatable with 4 columns and I'm creating observable collection with simple if from it:

```cs
    DataTable dt = await CallWebServiceTemp(lines);
    temperatureData = new ObservableCollection<object>();

    if (dt != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            temperatureData.Add(dt.Rows[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
       //code to deal with that
    }

    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Temperature));
```

This observable collection is bound to ListView in XAML through Temperature:

```cs
    public ObservableCollection<object> Temperature
    {
        get { return temperatureData; }
        set { temperatureData = value; }
    }
```

Listview is created in XAML like this:

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Temperature}" FlexLayout.AlignSelf="Auto">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="{Binding ItemArray[0]}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Label Text="|" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding ItemArray[1]}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Label Text="|" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding ItemArray[2]}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Label Text="|" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding ItemArray[3]}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Now as I stated earlier, this works just fine in Andoird and UWP, but not in iOS. In there I get the right number of items in the listview, but no data passed through ItemArray in the label, they're empty.

Clearly I'm missing something.

Comment: I'm a little surprised this works at all.  I've only seen bindings done with strongly typed objects and collections.  I'd suggest creating a custom class for your data instead of using a DataTable and an ObservableCollection<object>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using Datatable because that's the data type I'm getting from used webservice, Listview is then used for quick and easy displaying of those data. So, you think it would be best to create class, fill it with content of the datatable and then use that class to display data?

Comment: that's the first thing that I would try

Comment: Forgot to reply here, I used new model class to store data and bind that to my UI as suggested. It works fine now. Thanks